# Display checked in checkbox theme admin page when reloaded

Tags: wp-admin, forms

When check in checkbox, display checked.
And when uncheck in checkbox, display unchecked.
it is OK.
But when reload this theme admin page, always unchecked.
When save checked and then reload, but display uncheceked.

I want to display checked if I reload this theme admin page, when check in checkbox and save.

Sorry broken English...

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['twitter'])) { update_option('twitter', $_POST['twitter']);}
$twitter = isset($_POST['twitter']) ? 1 : 0;
update_option('twitter', $twitter);
echo $_POST['twitter'];
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<label for="twitter"><input type="checkbox" name="twitter" id="twitter" value="1" <?php checked( get_option('twitter'), 1); ?>>twitter</label>
<p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button-primary" value="Save"></p>
</form>
<?php
echo esc_attr(get_option('twitter'));
?>
```